# Positive Validation Check Django Not Working

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

I have to create this validation rule when Start= (start_new + start_old) >0 or is positive and End = (end_new + end_old) >0 or is positive then the validation error will raise that" Positive Strat and Positive   End  are not allowed in the conjunction",

But with my below code it is not checking the validation rule and allowing the positive start and positive end values in the conjunction.

my code in django form.py

```html
        for i in range(count):
            start_new = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-start_new') or 0)
            start_old = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-start_old') or 0)
            end_new = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-end_new') or 0)
            end_old = int(self.data.get(f'applicationruntime_set-{i}-end_old') or 0)
            if (start_new + start_old) > 0 and (end_new+end_old) > 0:
                raise ValidationError(
                    f" Positive Start  values and Positive End  values are not allowed to be used in conjunction")
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `start_new`, `start_old`, `end_new` and `end_old` return correct values?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak Hi, How i can do it , i do not know that

Comment: If you are using some IDE like VSCode/PyCharm then put a breakpoint on those lines (or even earlier to check what is inside `self.data` )and call method with this code in debug mode. Here is some tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8QHoVam1-I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change priority:

```
((start_new + start_old) > 0) and ((end_new+end_old) > 0)
```

but this way is better:

```
(start_new > start_old) and (end_new > end_old)
```

and, of course, OOP is much better:

```
if not self.date_range_is_valid():
    ...
```

and somewhere you should define the method `date_range_is_valid`. It help you to  have validation method and change it for business asks.